# XIB required initializers - no storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

[Click Here For Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya7gq.png)

Hey, in the image I am simply creating a view controller that manages a blue view. 
When I create and initialize everything in the AppDelegate.swift, everything works regardless of whether or not I comment out the 2 top initializers (commented out in green in the photo).

I heard from other developers that when working with XIB and not story board, the 2 initializers are required. Can someone explain to me why it works even if I don't have them?

Comment: Please paste your code in the question,  not a screen shot

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to the objective-c tag. You may want to consider removing it. Also consider posting the code from the App Delegate so others can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any non-optional properties in your subclass and you do not want/need to do anything else in the initialisers, the superclass initialisers are all you need, and these are called automatically.

If you did have a non-optional property and therefore needed an initialiser or if you implemented an initialiser for some other reason, then you would have to implement both required initialisers.